# Use plyr to apply functions stored in lists

Tags: r, plyr

I'd like to use **plyr** to calculate multiple empirical cumulative distribution functions using `ecdf()`, and then apply those functions appropriately to entries in a data frame. For instance:

```
# Use the diamonds dataset in ggplot2
library(diamonds)
library(plyr)

# Calculate an ecdf for each combination of cut and color
all_ecdfs <- dlply(diamonds, c("cut", "color"), function(x) ecdf(x$carat))

# Make a dataset of specific diamonds, which I want to compare to the larger set
# My particular subset of diamonds
my_diamonds <- ddply(diamonds, c("cut", "color"), summarise, 
               my.carat=runif(n=1, min=0.5, max=1))
```

If I were to do this manually, it would look something like this:

```
# Use the ecdf for the first entry: cut=="Fair" and color=="D"
my_diamonds$percentile <- NA
my_diamonds$percentile[my_diamonds$cut=="Fair" & my_diamonds$color=="D"] <- 
            all_ecdfs[["Fair.D"]](my_diamonds$my.carat[my_diamonds$cut=="Fair" & my_diamonds$color=="D"])
```

Seems like there should be some way to use `ldply` or `lapply` to do this automatically, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it using `dplyr` to make the ecdfs, and vectorizing to get the values for your data.

```
#get ecdfs
library(dplyr)
z <- diamonds %>% group_by(cut, color) %>%
                  summarise(x = list(ecdf(carat)))
```

Now you have a dataframe `z` with the functions in a list in column `x`.

Call the function on our data. We go by row, and get the matching cut and color, then call the function on carat:

```
z$x[z$cut == my_diamonds$cut & z$color == my_diamonds$color][[1]](my_diamonds$my.carat)
```

Comment: Interesting that `dplyr` can make data frames with columns that are lists, but (as far as I can tell) `plyr` can't.